# how to import whole Material UI library in React JS

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I am creating React web page using Material UI. For using any element I need to import that element.
So I want know how to import whole Material UI library.

Comment: [This](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/) will help you I believe.

Comment: Don't import whole of Material UI. It's bad practice. The Library is very large about 5 mb @material-ui/core. So, your website will be necessarily bloated with code you don't really use. It will slow down the load time of the website.

Comment: But if you really want to do it, then here's how you import all. `import * as UI from '@material-ui/core`. Use can then use it like this. `<UI.Button />`

Comment: @TomBombadil Thanks for suggestion i will definitely follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we import  required components in particular component so same we have to follow when we import material-ui. Hence in individual component we have to add import statement with particular components as::

```
 import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
```

or if multiple components then we can use comma separated import as

```
import { Button, Text } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

in this article, https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/

Answer (score 0):

To import material ui library as a whole with every single feature, you need to install multiple dependencies and import all of them.
First Import

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

The font cdn link used by material UI is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
```

The icons of the material UI cdn link is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

The svg icons in material UI

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/icons

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```